# How to pass parameter to type option of nslookup in powershell?

Tags: powershell, nslookup

Here I want to run `nslookup` with specified types of DNS records in PowerShell.
I tried it by define the types of DNS records and run `nslookup` with `Foreach`.

```
$types = @("soa", "a")

Foreach ($type in $types){
    nslookup -type=$type google.com
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work because `$type` is not recognized as a parameter.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: btw. as u are on PowerShell you can use resolve-dnsname instead of nslookup: Resolve-DnsName -Type soa -Name google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote the whole argument, including the parameter name, with double-quotes - this will prevent PowerShell from interpreting `-type` as a managed parameter:

```
nslookup "-type=$type" google.com
```